# mysql to $_POST to json to php ... how can fix it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

I get tired with this code :(

I have 3 file :

1. index (include ajax.js)
2. reg.php
3. procese.php (on remote server)

(index) with 2 text using ajax.js to get data from remote MySQL as json by procese.php
customer id:
customer name:

just I Want Receive customer id & name after open index page :(

Code for ajax.js:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
async: true,
url: "reg.php",
data: {
customer_name: response_data.customer_name,
customer_id: response_data.customer_id,
},
cache: false,
global: false,
dataType: "json",
error: function(xhr,text_status,e){
//error, display the generic error message        
},
success: function(response_data){
//do nothing   
}
```

code for reg.php

```
$db = connect_db();
$data['customer_name'] = $_POST['customer_name'];
$data['customer_id'] = $_POST['customer_id'];
settings_update($data,$db);
```

code for procese.php (on remote server)

```
$_POST = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
 $customer_name = $row['customer_name']; 
 $customer_id = $row['customer_id']; 
 $_POST[] = array('customer_name' => $customer_name, 'customer_id' => $customer_id); 
 }


foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
echo json_encode($_POST);
}

 $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
 $customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];
```

Comment: cant you use any other variable instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Have you tried to put your `echo json_encode($_POST)` outside the loop? Anyway I think it's a bad idea to write to `$_POST`

Comment: please if you have any other code to get my idea ..just I Want Receive customer id & name from remote php by any way ... after open index page :(